# prove/disprove: for all odd $n \geq 3$ we have $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} p_k(n-k) \not \equiv 0\mod n$

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, finite-groups

Assume $p_k$ is the $k$th prime. I really don't know where to start except the fact I know that the numbers modulo $n$ form a group with the addition operator. All I know about the primes is multiplication related. Is there any theorem that I am missing out here?

By the way, I know this is true for all even $n \geq 2$ but I can't prove/disprove for odd $n$'s.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The claim is equivalent to $\sum_{k=1}^n kp_k\not\equiv 0\pmod n$

Comment: It is somewhat disappointingly false, as can be seen by n = 21 (I wrote a program).

Comment: @Countingstuff Even the "known" part about even $n$ has exceptions, cf. my answer

Comment: Yah. My intentions were different, I was just about to edit it but you got it first. But it's still interesting to know both are not true, and to see the sequence in the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=21$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}p_k(n-k)=4200 = 21\cdot 200 $$
and for $n=98$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}p_k(n-k)=687078 = 98\cdot 7011. $$
The sequence of $n$ for which $n\mid \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}p_k(n-k)$, begins
$$1,2, 21, 31, 39, 98, 343, 889, 891, 1957, 3250, 4493, 9182, 19587, 97017, 112339, 249617, 259895, 497901, 960730, \ldots $$
(and is not yet known to the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+21%2C+31%2C+39%2C+98%2C+343))